# Using jQuery to select all elements that have at least 2 children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I need to select all the `.sortable` `<ul>` elements, but I only need those that have 2 or more children (`<li>` elements).

Is there some way for jQuery to just select `<ul>` elements that have at least 2 `<li>` children? Thanks!

This code also would select the first `<ul>` in this example, which should be actually ignored (because it only has 1 child).

```js
$('ul.sortable:has(li)').sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  placeholder: 'list-group-item holder list-group-item-warning'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list list-group mb-4 sortable">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="2">Amarillo</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list list-group mb-4 sortable">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="1">Azul</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="3">Rojo</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list list-group mb-4 sortable">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="9">Verde</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="8">Cafe</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="6">Naranja</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-id="7">Rosado</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('ul.sortable').filter(function(){
   return $(this).children().length > 1;
}).sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    placeholder: 'list-group-item holder list-group-item-warning'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter` with a callback function:

```js
const uls = $('ul.sortable:has(li)')
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('li').length >= 2;
  });
console.log(uls.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list list-group mb-4 sortable">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="2">Amarillo</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list list-group mb-4 sortable">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="1">Azul</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="3">Rojo</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list list-group mb-4 sortable">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="9">Verde</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="8">Cafe</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="6">Naranja</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="7">Rosado</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
$('.sortable li+li').parent()
```

Comment: Will needlessly initialize plugin numerous times on same element